# Use SendGrid X-SMTPAPI to send message with same html but different attachments

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I'm implementing a method using Sendgrid API which must send invoices to our customers,  the message body is almost the same but the customer name, that I change with a replacement and substitutions without problem, but for each message I need to add two different attachments , I'm traying to accomplish this with X-SMTPAPI but I can't find if there's a way to add different attachments for each message, I'm using C#.

If there's no way to get this with X-SMTPAPI, Can I use transactional message? Each time that the process is run, must sent 1000 mails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no way to pass per-message attachments via X-SMTPAPI. You can send one message per recipient with the necessary attachments as you suggest. This will be slower due to increased number of connections and SMTP exchanges, but it will work. You may want to look at using a BackgroundWorker or a queue to accomplish this without impacting other systems.

Comment: Thank you @bwest !!, You should put this information in SendGrid documentation.